# Combining a point plot with a histogram

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions, histograms

Hi everyone and sorry for my english, I'm new to Mathematica. I have a problem combining points with histograms in Mathematica 12.0.
I would like to display a frequency histogram along with points placed in the center of each bin. My ultimate goal is to put together a histogram with its Gaussian approximation.
I tried using `Show` to display them together but the points are not centered in the bins and moreover the histogram is moved to the right. At this point, I would have another question to ask you: how can I create a Gaussian curve starting from Gaussian points (with `ListLinePlot` the graph is broken and I don't like it)? Here is the code of my attempt.

Thank you in advance.

```
 istomax900 ={{0.0246604, 4}, {0.0258038, 3}, {0.0269472, 6}, {0.0280907, 
  14}, {0.0292341, 21}, {0.0303775, 14}, {0.0315209, 12}, {0.0326643, 
  10}, {0.0338078, 11}, {0.0349512, 6}}
     gaussianamax900={{0.0246604, 1.57199}, {0.0258038, 3.60887}, {0.0269472, 
  6.88537}, {0.0280907, 10.9177}, {0.0292341, 14.3863}, {0.0303775, 
  15.7544}, {0.0315209, 14.338}, {0.0326643, 10.8445}, {0.0338078, 
  6.81618}, {0.0349512, 3.5606}}
    Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[istomax900], Length[istomax900]]
    Show[ListPlot[gaussianamax900], 
     Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[istomax900], Length[istomax900]]]
```

Comment: People are less likely to help you if you do not provide code that other people can easily copy and paste. Don't force other people to retype your code.

Comment: ehm sorry , it's my first question.

Comment: It's fine, that's why I'm teaching you how things are done here. Does `Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[istomax900], Length[istomax900], Epilog -> {Red, Point[gaussianamax900]}]` do what you want?

Comment: This allows me not to use "Show" but the points in the bins are not centered anyway

Comment: By "centered", do you mean the points are centered on the bars, or centered on the tops of the bars?

Comment: I mean centered on the bars. 
The coordinates of my points should satisfy this request

Comment: "centered on the bars" - so, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeUgS.png)?

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself wrong. I meant centered on the axis of the bins. @kglr gave me the answer I wanted. Thanks again, and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: ah, the *tops* of the bars.

Comment: No, @kglr answered me in update answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here are a few options for you to start. Try to experiment by reading examples in documentation for listed below functions.

```
data=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1,3],10^3];

f1=NormalDistribution[1,3];
f2=FindDistribution[data];

options={Filling->None,PlotStyle->PointSize[.02]};

Show[Histogram[data,20,"ProbabilityDensity",PlotTheme->"Detailed"],
DiscretePlot[PDF[f1,x],{x,-10.5,10.5},#]&@@options]

Show[Histogram[data,20,"ProbabilityDensity",PlotTheme->"Detailed"],
DiscretePlot[PDF[f2,x],{x,-10.5,10.5},#]&@@options]

Show[Histogram[data,20,"ProbabilityDensity",PlotTheme->"Detailed"],
DiscretePlot[PDF[f2,x],{x,-10.5,10.5},#]&@@options,
Plot[PDF[f2,x],{x,-9,9},PlotStyle->Opacity[.3]]]

Show[Histogram[data,20,"ProbabilityDensity",PlotTheme->"Detailed"],
Plot[PDF[f2,x],{x,-9,9}]]
```

Comment: @kglr gave me the correct answer. 
Thank you for your availability

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Using OP's data:

```
bincenters = istomax900[[All, 1]];
binwidth = First @ Differences[bincenters];
binspecs = {Min[#] - binwidth/2, Max[#] + binwidth/2, binwidth} & @ bincenters;

Show[Histogram[WeightedData @@ Transpose[istomax900], binspecs], 
 ListPlot[gaussianamax900, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]; 

histogram = Histogram[data];
```

You can extract the coordinates of bin centers and heights from `histogram` using [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and use those points with `ListLinePlot`:

```
bincentersandheights = Cases[histogram , Rectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, ___] :> 
  {Mean[{xmin, xmax}], ymax}, All];

Show[histogram, ListLinePlot[bincentersandheights,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotMarkers -> "●"]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `bincentersandheights` to construct the desired points and lines to be used as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Show[histogram,  Epilog -> ({Thick, Red, Line@#, PointSize[Large], Red, Point@#} &@
   bincentersandheights)]
```

> same picture

Comment: Perfect. You have fully satisfied my request. Thank  you very match.

Comment: @tommaso if kglr’s answer solves your problem, consider upvoting it and accepting it to reward their effort.

Comment: yes , sure. I click on the v, all right?